# Only choose first sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that appends all files in a folder in one workbook. Can I change the code, so it will only append the first sheet in each workbook? The name of the first sheet is the same in each file. Thank you in advance :)

```
Option Explicit
' REMEMBER TO CHANGE FOLDER DIRECTORY

Sub CombineFilesInSheetsFood()
     
    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet
     
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\Users\c2200102\OneDrive - Coor Service Management\Desktop\Append\2022\" 'Change as needed
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
Option Explicit
' REMEMBER TO CHANGE FOLDER DIRECTORY

Sub CombineFilesInSheetsFood()
     
    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet
     
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\Users\c2200102\OneDrive - Coor Service Management\Desktop\Append\2022\" 'Change as needed
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        
        
       ' For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
          '  WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets)
        'Next WS
        
        
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```